# Unlimited Colour Schemes in wp theme for Zurb Foundation with reduxframework

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, zurb-foundation-5

I am developing a WordPress theme with Zurb Foundation 5 framework and ReduxFramework as Theme Options panel. So, there is various way that i can implement Colour Schemes for WordPress theme.

1. Using Different Style Sheets with different colour Schemes.
2. Using css class and id
3. +many more way........

But, I don't want to do this way. ReduxFramework can dynamically change css files and write class or id. And I want to do this way. So i can modify Foundation 5 css style sheet class and id from ReduxFramework Options panel dynamically. And After changing, it's must change Theme colour schemes.

Foundation 5 comes with 6 main colour options. I want to change those from ReduxFramework options panel.

1. Primary Color
2. Secondary Color
3. Alert Color
4. Success Color
5. Body Font Color
6. Header Font Color

Also is there any way that i can modify or change every options that comes with Foundation 5 CSS framework from Redux Framework.

Please go to this image link. {Open this image in a new tab for bigger view}

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YI0aD.png
```

Now question is, How can i do those things ?

I know short of PHP, JS, HTML, CSS, MYSQL etc. If you describe everything in your answer, it's will be more helpful for me.

This Question is RE-POSTED from [Unlimited Colour Schemes in wp theme for Foundation 5 - WordPress Development Stack Exchange:](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/182755/unlimited-colour-schemes-in-wp-theme-for-foundation-5) . One reputed user suggested me to ask this question here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer given by @Dovy is right in the basics. As far as i know there is no Less version of foundation. So you will need Foundation's Sass (SCSS) files and a SASS (php) compiler.

It seems Redux has a Sass compiler built in too: [Redux and Sass](http://reduxframework.com/2014/12/redux-sass/)

1. Install Foundation code, for instance by running `bower install foundation` in your WordPress folder.
2. Install a php Sass compiler, see: http://leafo.net/scssphp/

Now in your Redux config file add a hook on save:

```
add_action('redux/options/' . $opt_name . '/saved',  "compile_sass"  );
```

Also see: https://github.com/reduxframework/redux-framework/issues/533

And finally add the `compile_sass` function to the config file (you can use the compile action as an example, see: http://docs.reduxframework.com/core/advanced/integrating-a-compiler/):

```
function compile_sass($values) {
    global $wp_filesystem;

    $filename = dirname(__FILE__) . '/style.css';

    if( empty( $wp_filesystem ) ) {
        require_once( ABSPATH .'/wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
        WP_Filesystem();
    }

    if( $wp_filesystem ) {
    require "scssphp/scss.inc.php";
    $scss = new scssc();
    $scss->setImportPaths("bower_components/foundation/scss/");

    // will search for `assets/stylesheets/mixins.scss'
    $css = $scss->compile('$primary-color: '.$values['primary-color'].';
    @import "foundation.scss"');

        $wp_filesystem->put_contents(
            $filename,
            $css,
            FS_CHMOD_FILE // predefined mode settings for WP files
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, actually this is quite easy. Foundation uses LESS or SCSS to compile that. They use variables that they pass into those compilers. So the easiest way to do this would be to have Redux use a compiler hook on those color fields, re-output the variables file, and re-run the compiler on the LESS/SCSS. Cake.  :)

Comment: Hi three @dovy . I am not fully familiar with LESS or SCSS. So, what should i do now? Is there any way that i can do it without using LESS or SCSS..

Comment: Unfortunately not really.The biggest value of LESS and SCSS (SAAS) is variables and mixins. Unless you want to do a mass search and replace (very slow) you're out of luck unless you incorporate LESS or SCSS. There's just no other way to really do it.

Answer (score 0):

I happened to get it working gathering info from the various comments but code reflecting newer versions of redux and foundation. Sharing code hoping someone finds this useful

```
/* sample redux fields = array(
 array(
        'id'       => 'theme-primary-color',
        'type'     => 'color',
        'title'    => __( 'Add Primary Color', 'theme-redux' ),
        'subtitle' => __( 'Add the theme primary color', 'theme-redux' ),
        'default'  => '#FFFFFF',
        'validate' => 'color',
        'compiler' => 'true',
    ))
*/

add_filter('redux/options/' . $opt_name . '/compiler', 'compiler_action', 10,3);

function compiler_action( $options, $css, $changed_values ) {
  global $wp_filesystem, $kavabase_options;

  $filename = get_template_directory() . '/assets/stylesheets/theme-style.css';

  if( empty( $wp_filesystem ) ) {
    require_once( ABSPATH .'/wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
    WP_Filesystem();
  }

  if( $wp_filesystem ) {
    require_once ( dirname(__FILE__ ) ."/plugins/scssphp/scss.inc.php" );

    //use Leafo\ScssPhp\Compiler; at the beginning of the file

    $scss = new Compiler();

    $scss->setImportPaths(  get_template_directory(). "/inc/foundation-sites/" );
   //$scss->setFormatter( "Leafo\ScssPhp\Formatter\Compressed" );

    $css =  $scss->compile('@import "foundationdependencies.scss"; $theme-primary-color: '.$options['theme-primary-color'].';
      @import "foundationsettings.scss";
      @import "foundationutil.scss";@import "foundation.scss"');

    //var_dump( $scss->getParsedFiles() );

    $wp_filesystem->put_contents(
      $filename,
      $css,
      FS_CHMOD_FILE // predefined mode settings for WP files
    );
  }
}
```